# "Are" vs. "Is" in the context

Tags: word-choice, subject-verb-agreement

Which person to follow here?

> 1- The number of students and the number of teachers **are/is** decreasing
>   day by day in school.
>
> 2- Either a number of teachers or a number of students **is/are** participating in the college's festival.

Answer (score 1):

Both are **are**.  Number (when referring to a group of things, as opposed to the numeric system itself), is *generally* seen/used as a plural (unlike couple, group and other mass nouns which are *generally* seen as singular).  See for example, [GrammarMonster](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/singular_plural_number.htm), [DailyWritingTips](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/is-number-singular-or-plural/).

In the examples above:

> The number of students and the number of teachers **are** decreasing day by day in school.

This is referring to the number (ie as a concept of the numeric system), but there are two of these numbers under discussion, so **are** is the only correct option.

> Either a number of teachers or a number of students are participating in the college's festival.

This uses number as part of the group so should generally be are, however, you would not be wrong by using the singular (is) if you wish to emphasise the fact that there won't be both teachers and students participating

Even when dealing with a single group, number remains plural:

> A number of teachers are participating in the college's festival
>
> A number of students are boycotting the festival.

However if there was only one group in the first sentence then 'number' would be referring to a single instance of a numeric system concept and would be used in the singular:

> The number ... is decreasing

Comment: While "is" is grammatically correct, the fact that the entity in question (a number, a lot, a great deal, etc.) is a collection of other entities overpowers grammatical considerations.  Use of the singular occurs but is uncommon.  An Ngram comparison of "a lot of things is" (which sounds funny to modern ears) and "a lot of things are" shows spikes of the former in periods of grammatical fanaticism (the teens and the late 20's, less so in the 60's).

Comment: mcal, so "The number of students and teachers *are* ..." is correct even if 'students' and 'teachers' are involved altoghether?

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with *number*, singular or plural can be tricky.

Consider this case:

> *Our safety program must be working; the number of accidents is/are dropping*.

[Is or are?](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+number+of+accidents+is%2Cthe+number+of+accidents+are&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) It's *is* because we are talking about **one** number: the number of accidents.

However, if we tweak the sentence:

> *Our safety program must be working; the number of injuries and the number accidents is/are dropping*.

Now, it's *are*, because we are talking about **two** numbers: the number of injuries, and the number of accidents.

So, in your first sentence, I would use **are**:

> The number of students is decreasing...
>   The number of teachers is decreasing...
>   The number of teachers and the number of students are decreasing...

In the second sentence, I would use **are**, too, but for a different reason. The key is that we have
**switched the article** from *the* to *a*.

> Either a number of teachers or a number of students is/are participating in the college's festival.

In this case, "a number of" doesn't refer to a specific quantity (as did "the number of" in the previous sentence); instead, "a number of" roughly means "many" (or "several"):

> Either several teachers or many students is/are participating in the college's festival.

We are talking about several teachers, or many students, so we use the plural.

Answer (score 0):

In your examples, because the subjects of the sentences are compound

> The *number of students* **and** the *number of teachers* ...

the verb must be plural.  Same as if your subject were:

> *Bob* **and** *Alice* ...

However, as other answers have pointed out, if it were not a compound subject, it could go either way, although I tend to prefer singular in this context (it sounds better to me):

> The *number of students* is decreasing...

But in other contexts, *are* sounds fine to me:

> A *number of students* are going to the drive-in.

To me the key difference is that in the first case, it is actually the number we are discussing.  The students aren't decreasing (unless they're also going on a weight loss plan), but the *number* of students is decreasing.  In the second case, we are talking about a group of students, and "number" is almost (not technically though) just an adjective describing those students.